# How can I create a variable named from a concatenation of strings and assign it a value created similarly?

Tags: string-manipulation, variable-definitions

I have got a list of strings,

`a = {"first","second","third"}`.

For each of those strings I would like to create a variable called "The" followed by its content, so `Thefirst`, `Thesecond`, and `Thethird`. And in each case I would like to assign the variable the value of a pathname of the form `DriveLetter:/doc/myfirst.txt`, etc., where `Driveletter` is a previously created variable holding, let us say, the value "C:\".

So to be even clearer, this is what I want to get:

```
Thefirst = "C:\doc\myfirst.txt"
Thesecond = "C:\doc\mysecond.txt"
Thethird = "C:\doc\mythird.txt"
```

I've tried

```
For[i=1,i<=3,i++,
Symbol["The" <> a[[i]]] = 
FileNameJoin[{DriveLetter, "doc/", StringJoin["my", a[[i]],".txt"]}]]
```

but this gives the error message

`Set::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[Thefirst] is Protected`.

How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: You can wrap `Symbol[...]` with `Evaluate`. Or use `With`. In any case you [probably don't want to use `For`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/38205)

Comment: Thanks, but replacing `Symbol["The" <> a[[i]]]` with `Evaluate[Symbol["The" <> a[[i]]]]` I get `Set::setraw: "Cannot assign to raw object \!\(\"C:\\\\doc\\\\myfirst.txt\"\)."`

Comment: That means it's already been assigned to. Alternatively, use `Evaluate@ToExpression["The"<>a[[i]], StandardForm, HoldPattern]`

Comment: That works. Many thanks! :)